# Can't load jquery on wordpress ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Good afternoon developers, I started to develop a small plugin just to start learning wordpress, my problem is that i wasn't able to load another version of jquery other than the default used by wordpress, which is the slim, the function i'm trying to build uses AJAX which i believe is not available on the slim version
The error i get is:

```
   jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery.post is not a function TypeError: jQuery.post is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://1upscratch.com/wp-content/plugins/calculadora-wordpress-plugin/js/memo.js?ver=4.9.8:21:9)
at l (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:29567)
at c (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:29869) undefined
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.post is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (memo.js?ver=4.9.8:21)
at l (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
at c (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

On the plugin file i have the following code to load the standard jquery

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
function load_scripts() {
//USAR JQUERY QUE POSSUI AJAX--------
wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js', '','', true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('memo', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "js/memo.js", array('jquery'));
wp_register_script('main', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/main.js');
wp_enqueue_script('memo');
wp_enqueue_script('main');
wp_localize_script('memo', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
```

the javascript function i wrote is:

```
function salvar_resultado(memoria)
{
    //PEGAR O RESULTADO DO VISOR
var result = document.getElementById('visor').innerHTML;
//CHAMADA JQUERY
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
    //AJAX
    var data = {
    'action': 'salvar_resultado',
    'resultado': result,  
            'memoria':memoria
};
// We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
});

}
```

and my php code on the plugin is:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_salvar_resultado', 'salvar_resultado');
add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_salvar_resultado', 'salvar_resultado');
add_action('wp_ajax_carregar_resultado', 'carregar_resultado');
add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_carregar_resultado', 'carregar_resultado');

function salvar_resultado() {
    $memoria = $_POST['memoria'];
$resultado = $_POST['resultado'];
global $wpdb;
$tabela = $wpdb->prefix . 'calc_memoria';
$wpdb->insert($tabela, array(
    $memoria => $resultado)
);
wp_die();
}
```

I believe it isn't working because of the jQuery library at least, but im not certain, any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. You are using slim version of jquery.  ajax not work in slim version.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

function load_scripts() {
    //USAR JQUERY QUE POSSUI AJAX--------
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', '','', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('memo', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "js/memo.js", array('jquery'));
    wp_register_script('main', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/main.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('memo');
    wp_enqueue_script('main');
    wp_localize_script('memo', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
```

Comment: no luck with this code, looks like it is still loading the slim version, i really dont know why i cant manage to unload the slim version of the library